# C# - Is it possible to get HTML code from Confluence page via REST API?

Tags: c#, rest, postman, confluence, confluence-rest-api

So far I've programmed an Azure Function GET request to get the content from a Confluence page with its ID. 
 I use Postman to show me the body from the page I got with the GET request (see below). 
However, what I want to get from the page is the HTML code from the content inside of it.

Is there a way I can achieve this? If so, how?

**Code (Visual Studio 2019):**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace LocalFunctionProj
{
    
    public static class Http
    {
        private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        [FunctionName("Http")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> getContentByID(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
              ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            //Set up Configuration Builder
            var confBuild = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            //Basic Authentication
            var user = confBuild["ConfluenceUser"];
            var api = confBuild["ConfluenceAPI"];
            var domain = confBuild["ConfluenceDomain"];
              httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", user, api))));

            object  body = null;

            //Get content from page
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(
                        $"https://{domain}/wiki/rest/api/content/1234"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               
                body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
            }
            return new OkObjectResult(body);
        }
    }
}
```

**Postman output (JSON):**

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "type": "page",
    "status": "current",
    "title": "Test",
    "space": {
        "id": 12345,
        "key": "Test",
        "name": "TEST - title",
        "type": "global",
        "status": "current",
        "_expandable": {
            "settings": "/rest/api/space/Test/settings",
            "metadata": "",
            "operations": "",
            "lookAndFeel": "/rest/api/settings/lookandfeel?spaceKey=Test",
            "identifiers": "",
            "permissions": "",
            "icon": "",
            "description": "",
            "theme": "/rest/api/space/Test/theme",
            "history": "",
            "homepage": "/rest/api/content/123456"
        }, .....
```

Comment: You can get only what Postman returns.  The HTTP source is a file on the server and you can only get the source if you have access to the server file system.

Answer (score 0):

To get the html, you need to 'expand' the body section by adding 'expand=body.storage' as a query parameter:

```
your url -> $"{_baseUrl}/rest/api/content/{Id}?expand=body.storage"
```

The raw HTML is found in 'Page.Body.Storage.value'